# function template as member - GCC vs. CLANG

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename F>
class function
{
public:
//  using function_type = typename std::decay<F>::type;
    using function_type = F;

    function(F func)
        : function_(func)
    {
    }

private:
     function_type function_;
};

template <typename F>
function<F> make_function(F&& func)
{
    return function<F>(std::forward<F>(func));
}

double f1(double)
{
    return 0.0;
}

template <typename T>
T f2(T)
{
    return T();
}

int main()
{
    // works in both cases
    make_function(f1);

    // needs decay (with CLANG)
    make_function(f2<double>);
}
```

The class `function` is intended to be a simple wrapper for any `Callable` . The code compiles fine with GCC (I tested both 4.9.2 and 7.0.0 20160427 from the git repository). However, clang (3.5.0) complains:

```
function.cpp:17:17: error: data member instantiated with function type 'function_type' (aka 'double (double)')
         function_type function_;
                       ^
function.cpp:55:2: note: in instantiation of template class 'function<double (double)>' requested here
        make_function(f2<double>);
```

So is this a bug of GCC? Why does it work if the variable is an argument (in `make_function` and the constructor) but not if it is a member variable? Is the decay (commmented out) in the right place or should I move it into `make_function`? Why does it make a difference if I pass a function (`f1`) or an explicit instantation of a function template (`f2`)?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't want to use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? Is this only a learning exercise?

Comment: shouldn't it be called by `make_function(&f2<double>);`? This way it compiles fine with clang too...

Comment: Clang bug, already fixed in [3.7](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kkR4cLV68Uyzwv82).

Comment: Seems clang considered `f2<double>` is a rvalue, thus binding to `double (&&) (double)` where `F = double(double)` and `f1` as a lvalue, binding to `double (&) double` where `F = double (&) (double)`.

Comment: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18645

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes I wont to avoid it because the code above is in a performance critical part. I also want to understand what is going on here.

Comment: And you have measured and benchmarked that using `std::function` is indeed a bottle-neck? Premature optimizations and reinventing the wheel are never good starting points, but measuring is.

Comment: I agree with you that premature optimization is a bad thing, but my aim is also to allow both approaches (which enables me to measure the performance in the first place).

Comment: Incidentally, `std::forward` is only really meaningful when used with a parameter pack

Comment: @JoelCornett: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @cschwan actually nvm; this is a perfectly valid use case

Comment: @T.C.: I compiled it with clang 3.8.0 and it works now. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @T.C.: Please make this an answer so that cschwan can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters point out, this was a bug in Clang.

The code started compiling with GCC 4.7.1 (perhaps even 4.7?), and Clang 3.7: See it on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/u4BAnK).

Comment: Here you go :) !